# Got IndexError: string index out of range

Tags: sentiment-analysis

I was trying this code, and I got the following error.
Someone, please help me!!

```
#Read the tweets one by one and process it
import csv
inpTweets = csv.reader(str(open('tweets.csv', 'rb')), delimiter=',', 
quotechar='|')
tweets = []
for row in inpTweets:
    sentiment = row[0]
    tweet = row[1]
    processedTweet = processTweet(tweet)
    featureVector = getFeatureVector(processedTweet, stopWords)
    tweets.append((featureVector, sentiment));
#end loop




IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-15-6eb83cd8111f> in <module>()
        7 for row in inpTweets:
        8     sentiment = row[0]
  ----> 9     tweet = row[1]
       10     processedTweet = processTweet(tweet)
       11     featureVector = getFeatureVector(processedTweet, stopWords)

  IndexError: string index out of range
```

Please help...

Answer (score 1):

I think you have tried to convert the opened file to string without reading it line by line and using delimiters. 
https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/csv.html

```
with open('file.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
    for row in data:
        print(row, end=',')
```

Comment: File "<ipython-input-23-824aca6c6611>", line 4
    print ','.join(row)
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax        This error is coming.

Comment: You want to print in on the same line or on different lines?

Comment: "print row " is enough if you want to print it on different lines

Comment: Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)